# How to open "Enter Network Credentials" in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, shell, winapi, windows-shell

I'm using the [Windows Shell API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_shell/) to access Network machines and their folders.

```
shellFolder.EnumObjects(hwnd, grfFlags, out enumIdList);

....

int result = shellEnum.Next(celt, out itemPidl, out numFetched);
```

I'm using the [`IShellFolder.EnumObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-enumobjects) method, which works great and I can get a list of machines in my Network.

However, when I try to get folders from these networks, it works only when there is no need of authentication to the machine. If there is a need of authentication, the method returns `0x80004005` (`E_FAIL`).

Windows File Explorer shows a prompt to "Enter Network Credentials" for these machines. How can I show the same prompt from my WPF program and continue based on user's credentials?

Comment: I assume you don't have a IShellView where these IShellFolders are displayed? What is the hwnd passed to EnumObjects? There are probably some undocumented interfaces used in these parts of the shell.

Comment: Refer: [Display "Enter network credentials" if required](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1863076b-e6e0-4476-baf6-db32ee0ab39f/display-quotenter-network-credentialsquot-if-required?forum=csharpgeneral) ,  or use [CredUIPromptForCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/asking-the-user-for-credentials) to create standard Windows credential dialog.

Comment: @Anders What do you mean? I mean, EnumObjects returns folders from the shared network machine IF I go and manually authenticate to that machine using Windows File Explorer. Otherwise, it returns E_FAIL. I want it to behave the same way as File Explorer -> Show authentication popup (or if there are better ways to do that, I'm open to them).

Comment: Do you provide a valid HWND?

Comment: @SimonMourier I will debug it again, but as far as it works good with other networks not requiring authentication, I suppose I provide valid HWND.

Comment: The purpose of the HWND is precisely to show UI when needed. If it's zero/null, no UI will be displayed.

Comment: @SimonMourier I made sure valid window HWND is getting past. Now it returns 0x80070035 ("The network path was not found") instead. Still no authentication popup from Windows (which happens when I double click network in File Explorer).

Comment: Oh, changed something and it works now! The issue was that windows HWND was not valid. I am using "new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;" now and it shows authentication popup!

@SimonMourier, if you can please answer to this question. I will mark it as accepted, may help other people who will have same issue as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the Shell API, a HWND handle can be passed, but it's optional, and it's also a way to say "disable UI".

This is the case for the [IShellFolder::EnumObjects method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-enumobjects)

```
HRESULT EnumObjects(HWND hwnd, SHCONTF grfFlags, IEnumIDList **ppenumIDList);
```

hwnd parameter official documentation:

> If user input is required to perform the enumeration, this window
> handle should be used by the enumeration object as the parent window
> to take user input. An example would be a dialog box to ask for a
> password or prompt the user to insert a CD or floppy disk. If
> hwndOwner is set to NULL, the enumerator should not post any messages,
> and if user input is required, it should silently fail.